# ArcGIS Runtime SDK Debug Display

Tags: xamarin.forms, arcgis, xamarin.uwp, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am developing an app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET in Visual Studio Community 2017, currently set to Debug configuration.

There are these two black boxes/squares with numbers in them, one floats top left of the app window and another one floats top right of my desktop.
I have outline the one floating in the app in red in the following image:
[Black box floating in app window with ArcGIS Runtime app for .NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBIGG.jpg)

I assume its some sort of debug information specific to the ArcGIS SDK but searching online has yielded no results and the documentation on the ESRI website does not seem to make mention of it.

Note: It does not display when running the app on an android device, only when running the UWP version.

I would like to know what they are (1) and (2) How to enable and disable them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a debug feature provided by UWP & Visual Studio. There are two black bars in the screenshot you posted:

- In the center is the XAML debugging tools. You can disable this by going to Tools> Options> Debugging> General and unchecking 'Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML'.
- On the left is the framerate counter. You can disable this in code:

in **App.xaml.cs** (within the UWP project):

```
    #if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
    }
    #endif
```

Note that the above code already exists in that file, but EnableFrameRateCounter is set to true.

Also note that those tools only appear in debug mode.

Learn more: [DebugSettings class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DebugSettings)

Comment: Cool thanks, sorry I cant up-vote due to low reputation as I am new here.